# How to detect bots spamming forms and log IPs & input?

Tags: php, javascript, spam-prevention

Hello all the community,

I have a website with decent traffic and after I analyzed some logs in AWStats I found there are a lot of bots that spam my search form with bad words (sex, young..., etc). This is a problem because every search contributes to a tag cloud.

I installed an anti-ddos script (on CentOS) but it does not fit my need for this and kills some search engine IPs (wich is pretty bad).

The search spam is coming from too many IPs so I cannot simply add them into deny IP list.  A good solution would be to monitor all POSTs and log them into a txt file with the search terms + IP addresses.

Here is the webform of my website:

```
<form action="<?= _domain ?>/search.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="q" value="<?=$q?>" id="query" /> 
  <select name="cat" style="margin-top: 5px;font-size: 16px;">
    <option value="all">All Files</option>
    <?php list_categories('dropdown', $cat); ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit" /><br />
</form>
```

Does someone know a javascript code, or something similar, that could help me in that way?

Thank you very much

Comment: Just store the words inside an array, and then cross check with user input, before submitting.

Comment: thx you, yes captcha is a good solution too but it's gonna loose interest since all website similar to my have no captcha

Comment: Please do not use a captcha to search. It is **horrible** for real users. Use `POST` for the search form and no legit crawler will use it.

Comment: "then store the words inside an array & then cross check user input",if i understand right you want me to insert a badwords list but my website have already this fonction & it does not work pretty well since they are to plenty , i think to ban by IP will be better ,but i need to know "who search for what"

Comment: thx you ThiefMaster, i see but i need these legit crawler crawl my website anyway , its more about some nasty search terms that i need to deny IP since they are always query my website & make it slower..

Answer (score 3):

One clever solution to this that I've seen is to include a "honeypot" input box and set its CSS display value to none.  If there is anything in that box, you know it's a script.  Also, use something really obscure for the real name of the field, and pass in a token you can validate upon submission.  For example:

```
<input type="text" name="zsdifhs" value="<?= $q ?>" id="zsdifhs" />
<input type="text" name="q" value="<?= $tok ?>"
    id="query" style="display:none;" />
```

Or possibly set it to the background color of your page; if that's white, something like:

```
<input type="text" name="zsdifhs" value="<?= $q ?>" id="zsdifhs" />
<input type="text" name="q" value="<?= $tok ?>"
    id="query" style="font-size: 1pt; color: white;" />
```

Or set it to some non-visible margin, like:

```
<input type="text" name="zsdifhs" value="<?= $q ?>" id="zsdifhs" />
<input type="text" name="q" value="<?= $tok ?>"
    id="query" style="margin-left: 9000px;" />
```

In the processing script, if `$_POST['q']` is set to anything except the token you passed in, you know it's almost certainly been modified by a script.  To avoid detection, you can also use javascript to change the CSS display status, and if you're feeling really clever, you can even do something fancy like return a static page with bogus results (which is pretty efficient) instead of actually processing the query instead of returning an error or access denied page, which the script would probably detect, allowing the attacker to check to see what's wrong and tweak their script.

Comment: what answer King Skippus thx you :) the code look good , if i implement your first code $_POST['q']=token passed in/out, how i can monitor the result script/bots/users ? is there a way to store a log into txt file or something ?

Comment: When you generate the page, create a random token of letters and store it somewhere (like in a tokens table in your database).  For example, the token for a given page load might be "Moacoaco", and you would insert that into a tokens table. Then when a form is submitted, check the submitted token to see if it exists in the tokens table. If so, delete it and continue processing the script normally. If not, then you've probably got a script running your page. At that point, I would probably return a static page of bogus results, log it, and after 10 attempts or so, start blocking the IP address.

Comment: i see King Skippus, even it's a good solution for now ,there is too much step to accomplish this since im not php developper , i understand but im not experienced to implement as you say , i know its not  a hard thing to code but need more learning ....thx you anyway m8

Comment: Even if you don't use token validation, I'd still suggest setting up the honeypot field and just leave it blank if you have to.  Then at least you can check it against an empty string and if it contains any data, you know you've got someone you probably need to block on your hands.

Comment: ok let's do it at least :)

Comment: It helps to use a something that might be a real form field but isn't, like full_name or user_email as your hidden field. The downside of this is that when legitimate users with a password manager use it to fill out the form, the PM may fill the hidden field. This code can help with that:

     <form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="off">